# Vertically centered images with Bootstrap in thumbnail and grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want vertically centered images with Bootstrap inside an grid class and in thumbnail class. The thumbnail classes should be same height. And the paragraph should be at the same level below the images.
Have tried everything possible and on the Internet search I have not found a suitable solution that works. Examples there are only images with grid or images with thumbnail, but not in combination with grid and thumbnail.
Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <div><img src="pics/logo_pic_height_100px.jpg" ></div>
            </div>
            <p>Some Text</p>
          </div><!--

          --><div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <div><img src="pics/logo_pic_height_60px" ></div>
            </div>
            <p>Some Text</p>
          </div><!--

          --><div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <div><img src="pics/logo_pic_height_120px.jpg" ></div>
            </div>
            <p>Some Text</p>            
          </div><!--

          --><div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <div><img src="pics/logo_pic_height_80px.jpg" ></div>
            </div>
            <p>Some Text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

That doesn't work!

```
.thumbnail{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: so you want the text block to be all the same?...I guess I am a little confused each picture has a different height?...I mocked up something tell me if this is close to what your experiencing.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLLqZq

Comment: The images have different heights cause there are different logos of different groups.

Answer (score 0):

The parent element containing `.thumbnail` must have `display:table;` for `vertical-align: middle;` to work. Best-practice is to use a `<table>` layout and assign `vertical-align` to elements you want aligned middle vertically, such as:

```
table, tbody, thead, th, tr, td, td table {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
td, th {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

`td` elements (or `.thumbnail` in your case) should be `display: table-cell;` inside the `display:table;` element.

Note that `line-height` value assigned to the parent element also has an effect when using `vertical-align: middle;` on it's children.

I would not advise using `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` as suggest above by others, it's simply not best-practice.